# How to set the previous Parent id on a Child column with Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, orm

I have parent and child entities:

```
@Entity
public class Parent{
@Id
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
private Child child;

.....
}

@Entity
public class Child{
@Id
private Long id;

public List<Parent> all parents;

**public Long lastParentId;**

.....

}
```

The issue is I need to update lastParentId in child every time I create parent.
In other words, child exists in DB before parent is being created, child is 'assigned' to him. And after every parent insert child's field should be updated with newly created parent id, and this id should be last for this child. In other words:

```
Long childId=12323L;//lastParentId in child with id=12323L is 1234

Parent p=new Parent();
...
p.setChildId(childId);

getDao().insert(p);//lastParentId in child=1235, 1235- newly created parent id
```

I tried to assign this column by manual max select, but it possible that between select max() and save other processes insert new parent, so last id becomes obsolete before child save. How can I do this in hibernate and ensure that this lastId is really last?

Comment: Once you persist the parent, can you not just grab its reference to child, update the id of that child to the parent's id, then persist the child?

Comment: Tahnk you, but I don't understand you, neither parent, nor child ids never changed, the issue occurs only in case of inserting new parent. This operation should be safe and guarantee that thi is exactly last id, even this child is being updated by other threads and other servers. I feel it's not easy to do, anyway I hope. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use a [BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) in the `Child` table, which check the old `parent_id` column and saves it to `last_parent_id`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER last_parent_id_check BEFORE UPDATE ON child
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.parent_id <> OLD.parent_id THEN
        SET NEW.last_parent_id = OLD.parent_id;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I did today, but I used after insert trigger on parent, and update child lastParentId there. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

change `public Long lastParentId;` to `@ManyToOne public Parent latestParent;` and update the `Child` when new `Parent` is created.